# How do I remove the label from the webform grid options?

Tags: 7, webforms, theming

We've upgraded to [Webform 7.x-4.2](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/releases/7.x-4.2)

We're using the grid input type.

[image: example]

In previous versions we just had the options along the top, now the label is being concatenated before the option.

So in bold along the top row show be "1" not "me-1"

How can I prevent this behaviour?